# Problema con las entidades de hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo un problema con hibernate que me dice que no estan mapeada las entidades. aqui esta el error:

```
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UsersEntity is not mapped [FROM UsersEntity ]
```

> Clase Main

```
    public class Main {
    private static final Session session;

    static {
        try {
            HibernateConnection hibernateConnection = new HibernateConnection();
            session = hibernateConnection.openSession();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main (final String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            List<UsersEntity> usersEntities = (List<UsersEntity>) session.createQuery("FROM UsersEntity ").list();
            usersEntities.forEach(usersEntity -> {
                System.out.println(usersEntity.getName());
            });
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

> Clase UsersEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "amazonviewer", catalog = "")
public class UsersEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }
}
```

> Archivo cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <mapping class="com.ahernand.entity.MaterialEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.ahernand.entity.MoviesEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.ahernand.entity.UsersEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.ahernand.entity.ViewedEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Clase de configuraciones de hibernate

```
public class HibernateConnection {

    private String DB_DRIVER_NAME   = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String DB_URL           = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/amazonviewer";
    private String DB_USERNAME      = "root";
    private String DB_PASSWORD      = "Admin123!";
    private String DIALECT          = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect";
    private String SHOW_SQL         = "true";

    private static Configuration config;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    public HibernateConnection () {
        config = new Configuration();

        config.setProperty("hibernate.connector.driver_class", DB_DRIVER_NAME);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", DB_URL);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", DB_USERNAME);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", DB_PASSWORD);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);

        /*
         * Config connection pools
         */
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000");

        this.sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    public Session openSession() throws HibernateException {

        if (session == null) {
            this.session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        return this.session;

    }

    public void reconnect() throws HibernateException {
        this.sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

Comment: Intenta Agregar el nombre explicito a la anotación @Entity (name ="UsersEntity")

Comment: pero amigo, ese nombre es el que tengo en la bases de datos

Comment: en la base de datos tienes user, tienes que poner la referencia del @Entity en tu clase UsersEntity y ver si con eso te funciona, el error que dices que te da es muy comun, normalmente se da por que en el createQuery se llama a la tabla de la base de datos cuando se tiene que llamar a la entidad de clase y eso lo haces bien. como te digo prueba colocando los parametros al '@entity' y ver si te funciona.

Comment: no, hago referencia al objecto en el query y no te entendi muy bien sobre que parametros hablas en @Entity

Comment: En tu clase UsersEntity el bean @Entity que tienes declarado puedes ponerle parametros, lo que te decia yo era que probaras referenciando tu entidad de la siguiente manera @Entity(name = "UsersEntity") y ver si con esto no te da problemas, te lo dejare como ejemplo en una respuesta.

Comment: El package corresponde al de configuracion del xml?

Comment: Si, ya le agregue los parametros que tu me dijistes, pero nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este error puede ser causado por muchas cosas, explicitamente te dice que no esta mapeando su clase  `UsersEntity`, pero a pesar de que te de ese error no necesariamente es así.

Algunas soluciones a este error son las siguientes:

1. En el Bean  `@Entity` declarado en tu clase prueba colocando lo siguiente:

   ```
     @Entity(name="UsersEntity")
   ```

Lo que haces es decirle explicitamente que esa es tu clase entidad, que es la que estas llamando cuando haces el  `createQuery()`.

2. Para su  `createQuery("from UsersEntity").List()` , debe tener siempre en cuenta que lo que se llama es al nombre de la clase, su objeto, su entidad para ser mas claro, el caso erroneo seria llamar a la tabla de base de datos, cuando debe usar la clase entidad.
3. Estas importanto el package incorrecto, por ejemplo:

   ```
   import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity; (Incorrecto)
   ```

   Deberia ser

   ```
   import javax.persistence.Entity; (Correcto)
   ```
4. Intenta lo siguiente en tu consulta CreateQuery

   ```
     session.createQuery("from com.ahernand.entity.UsersEntity")
   ```

   lo que haces en este caso es usar la ruta completa de tu objeto, esto sin duda puede funcionar pero no es la mejor practica, debes fijarte bien que la clase se este importando desde su package correcto, en el archivo de configuraciones y en tu clase.

---

**PD**: Si la solución número cuatro te sirve para esto, sera una solución parche por el momento, pero te recomiendo no hacer esto, puedes probar y decirnos como te va, tengo una duda sobre si estas ocupando otros archivos de configuracion más como por ej:  `persistence.xml` o  `.hbm.xml`, si es asi podrias colocarlos en la pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Nada amigo, ni colocando el `UsersEntity.class` ni modificando el argumento de `Entity`

Comment: de casualiadad probaste si tu clase de conexion funciona bien? intenta de hacer un debbug y ver si hay algo por ahi que puede estar fallando.

Comment: ya hice el debug, exactamente me tira el error cuando me va a ejecutar el query

Answer (score 0):

Asdrubal.

Por favor verifica que la importación de la anotación sea javax.persistence en vez de org.hibernate...

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
```

Comment: Esta correcto, es de javax.persistence

Comment: En la configuración actualmente estas colocando el nombre de la base de datos. Por favor intenta modificando de esta forma

@Table(name = "users")

Answer (score 0):

Solamente implementa de la interface Serializable para decir que tu entidad pueda ser serializada y deserealizada. Saludos.

```
public class UsersEntity implements Serializable { ... }
```